# Is it faster to use else/if statements or a SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, performance, perl, xml-parsing

I am building an application that displays information on a web portal.
I have some X number of card readers in a building and these card readers talk to a controller in the same building. If there's any swipe on the card readers, they send the info to the controller and the controller writes it to a database.

I have to display this card reader info on a web page as soon as the swiping event happens.
so I am using perl Pcap to capture packets between the controller and database, reading the payload, parsing it like "if nth bit is this print this else if, print this" and I repeat the same else if process for door numbers, card numbers, door open/locked status etc.

So my question is, which one is faster? A program that fetches latest data from the SQL database to update the webpage or the else if iterations, that parses the data and then write it to an XML database and a subscribe script running to update the web page?

Comment: My gut feeling is that the database is less efficient, since it has to do lots of disk access. But the only real way to tell is to measure. Specifics of your architecture can be an important factor.

Comment: If you go with the pcap method, you might want to look into the library used for writing tcpdump/wireshark decoders, so you don't have to implement all the if/then stuff yourself.

Comment: Do you have a speed problem?  Do you have some sort of minimum metric you must meet?  Worrying about speed without having any sort of measurements or any sort of targets is stumbling around blind.  Get a working solution, then if it's too slow, worry about optimizing it.

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you that you'll get better performance with a SQL query (unless there's something convoluted and malformed in your query) than by retrieving the entire data set and implementing the same search and select logic in your program. Databases are optimized for these kinds of operations and are much faster at it than any programming language, especially an interpreted language like Perl.

Comment: @AndyLester My application is finished and running. The application was started by someone else and they used IF-MAP(IF-MAP.org) as a metadata database to store all the data. so i was wondering which method gives us better performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real answer is: Go, profile both.

Things to consider:

- Extracting data from the packets feels like a kludge. Ugly, hackish, prone to breakage, unmaintainanble.
- “XML database” is a lie. Use a real DB instead.
- Duplicating your information across multiple databases may be unnecessary redundancy, and opens the possibility of both information repositories getting out of sync. On the other hand, using seperate databases for seperate purposes can have various benefits.
- Some databases allow you to install triggers that are executed when a new record is added to a table. Using a trigger that pushes new events to the web interface may be the most efficient solution.
- Another solution would be having one job regulary polling the DB for new events that acts as a cache for the web interface. This would probably be no more expensive than running pcap.